# The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$, i.e., the smallest $\sigma$-algebra contained in $\mathcal{P}([0,1])$ which includes the intervals $O \cap [0,1]$, with $O$ open in $\mathbf{R}$.

Also, denote by $\mathscr{A}$ the $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ generated by
$$
\{x \in [0,1]: f_n(x)=1\},
$$
where $f_n(x)$ is the $n$-th digit in the nonterminating dyadic representation of $x$. It is clear that $\mathscr{A}\subseteq \mathscr{B}$.

> **Question** Is it true that $\mathscr{A}=\mathscr{B}$?

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ should be generated by subsets of $[0,1]$, not by points.

Comment: Indeed, $\{x \in [0,1]: f_n(x)=1\}$ is a subset of $[0,1]$ for each fixed $n$.

Comment: The answer is definitely "Yes". See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1960091/ for the proof.